# Simulating in omnet++ takes too much time

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm simulating a Network with more than 5000 nodes in Omnet++ 5.0 & Inet 3.4. Pure me that it takes too much time waiting.

I did simulation in Cmdenv, and added some stuffs in **omnetpp.ini** file like:

**record-eventlog = false**

**vector-recording = false**

**scalar-recording = false**

**statistic-recording = false**

**cmdenv-performance-display = false**

**cmdenv-express-mode = true**

But even nothing changed.

I notice that the initializing network phase takes a very very long time.

Please help me to find out!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked a similar general question in the Omnet++ Google Group a few years ago... and received a reply
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/omnetpp/LR9f8ClqwuQ/U2zgMEgi6YgJ

That can be summarized as follows:

1. Run simulation in the command shell environment. You are already doing that.
2. Try different GCC compiler options. Make sure you have at least `-O2`
3. Consider parallelization

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri Chubarov. 
My Network has only 1 scenario, but it's a huge network. Could I run in parallelization? Athough I tried to set "Processes to run in parallel" is 2 in Run configuration, because my laptop's CPU has 2 core. But it seem not improve the speed.

Comment: In order to use parallel simulation you have to partition your network, it is described in [Simulation Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:parallel-exec). Moreover, there is an example, `cqn` in `samples` which uses parallel simulation. However, I suggest building `INET` in `gcc-release` mode first. Setting `Processes to run in parallel` in `Run Configuration` is used when experiment is repeated or several values of parameter are defined. You use only one scenario, so this option does not help you to decrease the simulation time.